# window.postMessage() to a new tab in ios safari

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, safari

i have tow html pages each one is served locally on a port (8000 & 9000):
  - One opens a new tab and sends a post message to it :

```
window.addEventListener("message", function(ev) {
 console.log(ev);
});

var authWindow = window.open('http://local-ip:9000');

setTimeout(function () {
  authWindow.postMessage("requestCr", "*");
}, 500);
```

the other waits till the original post a message then respond with an object then closes

```
window.addEventListener("message", function(ev) {
    // this page must respond to "requestCr"
    if (ev.data === "requestCr") {
      ev.source.postMessage({"first_name": "jorge", "last_name": "willow"}, '*');
      // close window after message is sent
      window.close();
    }
  });
```

this script works fine in modern desktop browsers but in Ios Safari it seams like the original window setTimeout doesn't fire till it's on focus.
Any work around to make the first window post message even if it's not on focus ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: this is was an issue on IOS 7, fixed in IOS 8